# Handlebars template accessing elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am using this code to render a template in my application -

```
var venuePage =
    '<div>' +
        '<div id="venuePage">' +
            '<div class="header"><a href="#" class="btn">Back</a><h1>{{title}}</h1></div>' +
            '<div class="scroller">' +
                '<div class="map">' +
                    '<span>{{venue_address1}}, {{venue_town}}, {{venue_postcode}}</span>' +
                '</div>'
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

template = Handlebars.compile(venuePage);
$(".map").text("new text");
```

After this I want to manipulate `.map` using `jQuery` This is not working as at the time that the jQuery code is being run the `.map` element is not currently in the DOM.

What would be the best way for me to achieve what I need?

Thanks

Comment: You can assign new variable into .map and recompile the template when you will need to change it.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

Template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-template">
    <div id="venuePage">
        <div class="header"><a href="#" class="btn">Back</a>
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="scroller">
            <div class="map"><span>{{venue_address1}}, {{venue_town}}, {{venue_postcode}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and JS (I am using jQuery)

```
//Asign data first time on load
var data = {
    title : "Sample location",
    venue_address1 : "416 Water St",
    venue_town: "NYC",
    venue_postcode: "10002"
};

var template = $('#template').html();

var templateCompile = Handlebars.compile(template);
$('body').html(templateCompile(data));

//Now some action occurs and it's time to update template

data.venue_address1 = "100 Water St";
data.venue_town = "NYC";
data.venue_postcode = "10000";


$('body').html(templateCompile(data));
```

Here is a demo app: http://jsfiddle.net/UMBGC/33/

If you need to change structure of div.map then use something like

```
<div class="map">
     {{#if map}}
     {{map}}
     {{else}}
     <span>{{venue_address1}}, {{venue_town}}, {{venue_postcode}}</span>
     {{/if}}
</div>
```

and start your application with

```
var data = {
    title : "Sample location",
    venue_address1 : "416 Water St",
    venue_town: "NYC",
    venue_postcode: "10002", 
    map: false
};
```

then update data.map to something else